# Using OLS regression with time-series data and measuring its uncertainty

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, predictive-models, least-squares, prediction-interval

Imagine I have two cities situated near each other.
People have buying patterns in both cities so similar that the number of a company's sales per day is very closely correlated.

[image]

My goal is to predict sales in city A given that I only know sales in city B.

So my questions are:

**1) Can I use regular OLS for this?**

Teaching an OLS model to understand the relation between city A and city B and then predicting city A on city B gives decent results of MAPE 5% (out of sample) with normally distributed residuals.

However, given that this is time-series data, I am thinking about looking somewhere towards timeseries-specific models, like ARIMA, etc.

- Should I choose some timeseries-related model or is it overthinking and OLS is good to go?
- What assumptions require me to move from regular OLS to timeseries-related models?

**2) I am specifically concerned with measuring uncertainty.**

I have seen that with timeseries models confidence intervals grow as prediction moves further in time.

- Can you please say whether it's also true in my case?
- What assumptions make intervals grow in time?
- If OLS is a suitable solution to the problem, what could be the approach to estimate confidence/prediction intervals?

Appreciated!